# Author and year displayed in separate column: which bibliography style is this?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I am trying to figure out which bibliography style this is:

[image: Bibliography sample]

I am using the `natbib` package with the `apalike` bibliography style, which is what I want for the right column, but I am missing the left column (author year). I think this is a nice addition for easier reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version with `biblatex`, because I find that `natbib` is really hard to customize.

For now, the length is manual (set to `100pt`) since this is the first time I've been trying to change `biblatex` this much and I'm not sure how to set it automatically. Although I doubt you should have longer last names, if they happen, you can just slightly increase that length. In the meantime, here are the results.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{#1}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
    \printnames[][-\value{liststop}]{labelname}\addcomma\space%
        \printfield{labelyear}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{100pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{1.5ex}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{lamport1982byz,
  title={The Byzantine generals problem},
  author={Lamport, Leslie and Shostak, Robert and Pease, Marshall},
  journal={ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems (TOPLAS)},
  volume={4},
  number={3},
  pages={382--401},
  year={1982},
  publisher={ACM}
}
@article{lamport1998part,
  title={The part-time parliament},
  author={Lamport, Leslie},
  journal={ACM Transactions on Computer Systems (TOCS)},
  volume={16},
  number={2},
  pages={133--169},
  year={1998},
  publisher={ACM}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{lamport1982byz} 

\cite{lamport1998part}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was hoping it might be a standard template, but it seems likely it might be custom, like the one you are proposing here. It looks very good! Thanks a lot for the code :)

Comment: @player I'm not aware of any template. But it might not exist (considering no-one answered until now).

Answer (score 3):

You can automate the choice of length with the following code

```
\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\newlength{\citelabelwidth}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\begingroup\defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}\usebibmacro{cite}\endgroup}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\citelabelwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \blx@setlabwidth{\citelabelwidth}{\usebibmacro{cite}}
}
\makeatother
```

This is similar to what `biblatex` does with numeric and alphabetic labels already.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\newlength{\citelabelwidth}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\begingroup\defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}\usebibmacro{cite}\endgroup}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\citelabelwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \blx@setlabwidth{\citelabelwidth}{\usebibmacro{cite}}
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{lamport1982byz,
  title={The Byzantine generals problem},
  author={Lamport, Leslie and Shostak, Robert and Pease, Marshall},
  journal={ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems (TOPLAS)},
  volume={4},
  number={3},
  pages={382--401},
  year={1982},
  publisher={ACM}
}
@article{lamport1998part,
  title={The part-time parliament},
  author={Lamport, Leslie},
  journal={ACM Transactions on Computer Systems (TOCS)},
  volume={16},
  number={2},
  pages={133--169},
  year={1998},
  publisher={ACM}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{lamport1982byz} 

\cite{lamport1998part}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography of the MWE]