# labels before entries in only one of two split biographies

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I use labels before entries in the bibliography, just as in the solution given in [Bibliography styles like authordate2 in biblatex or natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44801/bibliography-styles-like-authordate2-in-biblatex-or-natbib/45147#45147), which works like a charm.
However, I need to limit the labels to just the first part of the bibliography (being the second dedicated to online sources without author) which I manage with filters as per MWE.
I'm using biblatex, biber, APA style, italian. I edit on Sharelatex.com.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}         
\DeclareLanguageMapping{italian}{italian-apa}

%LABELS
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {
        \printtext[]{%
            \begingroup
            \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
            \printfield{labelyear}% 
            \printfield{extrayear}%
            \endgroup
            }%
        }
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{100pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hfill##1\hss}
      }
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\defbibfilter{online}{
    type=online
}

\defbibfilter{offline}{
    type=book or
    type=article or
    type=report
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@online{cit1,
  title = {Title},
  url = {http://www.website.com},
  timestamp = {2013-04-11T17:20:44Z},
  titleaddon = {Example},
  urldate = {2013-04-10},
  date = {2004}
}

@report{cit2,
  author = {BBBAuthor, Name},
  title = {Title Title Title},
  url = {http://www.example.com},
  timestamp = {2013-04-11T17:20:44Z},
  titleaddon = {Website Name},
  urldate = {2013-04-10},
  date = {2004}
}

@book{cit3,
  location = {Location},
  title = {Title Title},
  timestamp = {2016-02-01T21:50:03Z},
  langid = {english},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  author = {Author, Name},
  date = {2001}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

Bla bla\footnote{\cite[]{cit1}, \url{http://www.website.com}}.
Bla\footnote{\cite[]{cit2}, \url{http://www.example.com}}.
Blaaa blaa bla\footcite[]{cit3}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,filter=offline,title={Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[title={Online},filter=online,heading=subbibliography]

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that your MWE does throws an error about `mymaxcitenames` not being defined, the MWE is missing `\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
    }` from the answer you linked to. See also [Author and year displayed in separate column: which bibliography style is this?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290545/35864) and [Adding an AuthorYear block at the beginning of bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be as easy as renaming your new bibliography environment to `bibwithlabels`, say.

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {
        \printtext[]{%
            \begingroup
            \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
            \printfield{labelyear}% 
            \printfield{extrayear}%
            \endgroup
            }%
        }
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{100pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hfill##1\hss}
      }
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

and use that for the offline bibliography with the `env` option

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,filter=offline,title={Bibliography},env=bibwithlabels]
\printbibliography[title={Online},filter=online,heading=subbibliography]
```